# g++ undefined reference to a free standing function

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

this must have been answered a million times, yet I cannot find a suitable solution.

I have defined a free function in `sensor.cpp`:

```
std::string printTargetGasName(enalu::CombThreshold::TargetGas){}
```

Then I have declared the prototype of the function

in `sensor.hpp`

```
std::string printTargetGasName(enalu::CombThreshold::TargetGas);
```

Then I include `sensor.hpp` in `core_enose.hpp` and try to use the function in `core_enose.cpp` (`enalu` is just a namespace).

I get `undefined reference` linking error

```
core_enose.cpp:284: undefined reference to `enalu::printTargetGasName(enalu::CombThreshold::TargetGas)'
```

the linking instructions in the make file seem correct, i.e. the sensor.opp comes after the core_enose.opp:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 [...] obj_dbg/core_enose.opp [...] obj_dbg/sensor.opp [...]
```

I also checked to see if the symbol correctly exists in the sensor.opp file:

```
$> nm obj_dbg/sensor.opp  | grep printTarget
$> 000000000000cc9c T _Z18printTargetGasNameN5enalu13CombThreshold9TargetGasE
```

I have tried desperate late night measures as well, such as `extern` , or re including the sensor.hpp directly in the core_enose.cpp file. Nothing helps and at this point I am frustrated at the simple answer that eludes me.

Note that I am not providing code because sensor.?pp files are rather big containing a few classes that I have also been using in my program. What I describe above are the exact steps I followed to add this free function to an otherwise working application.

Could you help me?

Comment: Is that exactly how you declared your function in sensor.hpp? I am surprised it even compiles

Comment: @YanZhou no , I have simply omitted the internals of the implementation between `{...}`. (also forgot to add the return of the function, fixed)

Comment: Yan Zhou's question is about the declaration in the .hpp file, not the implementation.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze It is fixed now. thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: show the link command and output without editing

Comment: Did you write `using namespace enalu;` and add the definition at file scope? Unmangling your symbol gives `printTargetGasName(enalu::CombThreshold::TargetGas)`, which is not in the `enalu` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your link error is about `enalu::printTargetGasName`, I suspect that you declared the function in your header within the `enalu` namespace, but the corresponding C++ doesn't have the namespace enclosure.  This might fix you in the `sensor.cpp` file.

```
namespace enalu
{
    std::string printTargetGasName(enalu::CombThreshold::TargetGas){}
};
```